# Is there a way to use ES6 modules to import modules with the ArcGIS API

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am currently trying to build a web app with the ArcGIS API.

[This article](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/mapping/writing-modern-javascript-with-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript/) seems to suggest that at some point in 2020, the API will receive native support for ES6 module import/exports.

Until then, how are people managing their projects? I am not currently planning on using Webpack or any framework. What is the suggested solution amongst ArcGIS JS developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you aren't planning on using webpack or a JavaScript framework then the ArcGIS API for JavaScript CDN (AMD) is a good choice for a plain HTML, JavaScript, CSS application: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/get-api/. There are hundreds of samples that demonstrate the APIs concepts using the CDN https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/

In addition to the information in Seth's summary above, an ES modules (beta) build will be available next month with the 4.18 release. You can preview the @arcgis/core modules today on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@arcgis/core). The ES modules build is initially aimed at local builds with a framework, module bundler (e.g. webpack or rollup) or a custom build. Here's a link to a blog post from a few weeks ago that gives an overview of these new modules: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/announcements/es-modules-are-coming-soon-in-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript/

Comment: Well this is great news. I look forward to trying this out